# Typescript: Null check doesn't work inside array.map function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Why my nullable type that was previously checked before the map function doesn't work inside the map?

```
function x() {
  let y: number | null;
  y = null;

  if (!y) {
    return [];
  }

  return [1, 2, 3, 4].map((z) => {
    // error: y cannot be null
    return z + y;
  })
}
```

[The code on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwBQEpEG8BQjEA2AplIgJ4BciYIAtgEZEBOiAPtSAQQNx7mIBeDl158YwRKgCEZTLnz4mJEEyQBtALq98AXxx8lUFeoCMAGkQAmCwGYLAFg0A6WgEMADqlQAvTAIB82HyKyqqI3ogA1OTaiDroODpAA).

Comment: In JavaScript null is "false-y", but type script is stricter. The exclamation point checks for false. You would need to compare y to Boolean false. Just some guidance; I don't know TS well.

Comment: @Sydney Y I've tried with  `y === null` and the error is the same

Comment: TypeScript basically cannot know when or even if `map()` will ever run its callback (since the signature for `map()` can't represent this), and it doesn't spend the time checking that `y` never gets reassigned after the closure is created (this would be a fairly expensive operation), so it errs on the side of saying that `y` might be `null` inside the closure.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for the general issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

As you are using `let` instead of `const` your type guard cannot guarantee that you will not modify the value, that said TS is taking the original assumption about the type (`number | null`), and you need to check it again. Changing `y` into `const` helps.

### Examples of re-assigning y

Consider that you could be after the check, again set `y` into `null`.

```
function x(defValue: number | null) {
  let y = defValue;
  if (!y) {
    return [];
  }
  // and below the change even though we checked that before the check is not safe
  y = null;
  return [1, 2, 3, 4].map((z) => {
    // no error
    return z + y;
  })

}
```

Another example how I can change the value is - in map itself, consider:

```
return [1, 2, 3, 4].map(z => {
    y = null // changed to null!!
    return z;
  }).map((z) => {
    // error as it can be null
    return z + y;
  })
```

The main reason why its not safe check is that we cannot say when callback will be called, fact that we declare it in this scope, does not mean it will be executed in the same time, for example if it would be `Promise.then`, time of execution is unknown. Consider such code:

```
function x(defValue: number | null) {
  let y = defValue;
  if (!y) {
    return [];
  }
  httpClient.get('http://something').then((z: number) => {
    // error correctly because y is null
    return z + y;
  });

  y = null; // this code is executed before then
}
```

Another example would be exposing possible change of `y` outside. Consider:

```
function x(defValue: number | null) {
  let y = defValue;
  if (!y) {
    return null
  }
  return {
    f: (z: number) => z + y, // error as y can be null because yToNull can change it
    yToNull: () => { y = null } // modify the y to null
  }
}
const fg = x(1);

if (fg) {
  fg.yToNull();
  fg.f(2); // y is null inside the scope of f
}
```

### Use const to have persistent guard

As you can see it is very unsafe to treat `let` variables as narrowed by guards in the whole closure.

With `const` such re-assign is not possible, and TS is able to infer the narrow type of the value in scope of closure.

```
function x(defValue: number | null) {
  const y = defValue;
  if (!y) {
    return [];
  }
  // any change of y type is not possible with const
  return [1, 2, 3, 4].map((z) => {
    // no error as y cannot be re-assigned
    return z + y;
  })

}
```

Comment: Fact : The `if(y === null)` should tell typescript that `y` cannot be `null` in the following lines. It works in the next lines (if you try to use `y` as `null`, it says `y` cannot be `null`. However typescript doesn't work like it should inside of the `map` functions.

Comment: It does but you can after modify it again to null, so this is not relevant check for the closure

Comment: `let` does not quarantee the narrowing is persitant. TS works correctly - treats `let` as something which can change in time

Comment: Good answer.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for the generally intractable problem surrounding control flow involving callbacks and mutation.

Comment: Such words from @jcalz :D

Answer (score -1):

As per documentation- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-and-non-undefined-type-guards.

> A property access or a function call produces a compile-time error if
>   the object or function is of a type that includes null or undefined.
>
> TypeScript 2.0 implements a control flow-based type analysis for local
>   variables and parameters. Previously, the type analysis performed for
>   type guards was limited to if statements and ?: conditional
>   expressions and didn’t include effects of assignments and control flow
>   constructs such as return and break statements. With TypeScript 2.0,
>   the type checker analyses all possible flows of control in statements
>   and expressions to produce the most specific type possible (the
>   narrowed type) at any given location for a local variable or parameter

If you try to access `y` after `if` condition, it will not show compiler error `Object possibly null`, because it has already been check for null in the `if` condition and is present in same scope.

```
  if (!y) {
    return [];
  }

  console.log(y); // No error.
```

Whereas, when you are accessing the `y` within the `callback` function of `map`, the scope is different. Instead you can use non-null assertion operator i:e !.

```
function x() {
  let y: number | null;
  y = null;


  if (!y) {
    return [];
  }

  return [1, 2, 3, 4].map((z) => {
    // error: y cannot be null
    return z + y!;
  })
}
```